# Paginating Azure CosmosDB with Python SDK using continuation tokens

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to implement pagination using APIs with [Azure Cosmos Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python). From what I have read and understand, we need `continuation tokens`. However, I cannot find any function in the SDK documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmos/azure.cosmos.container.containerproxy?view=azure-python#methods), that would consume the token and return the remaining data from the queries. My flow currently:

- Initialize CosmosClient
- Get database object
- Get container object
- Query the container, set `max_count_size=1`
- Get Paged response, send it as a response to the API call

Now if I want the next `page` from the query, where do I pass the continuation token so that I can get the next `page` based on the previous query for API call?

```py
from azure.cosmos import exceptions, CosmosClient, PartitionKey
endpoint = "https://xxxxxxxx.documents.azure.com:443/"
key = '===xxxx===xxxx===xxx'

client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)
database_name = 'test'
database = client.create_database_if_not_exists(id=database_name)
container_name = 'FamilyContainer'
container = database.get_container_client(container_name)
query = "SELECT * FROM c "
items = container.query_items(
        query=query,
        max_item_count=1,
        enable_cross_partition_query=True
    )

pager = items.by_page()
first_page = list(pager.next())
print("first page: ", first_page )
```

Now, if I want the next page in another API call, where do I pass the `continuation token`?
Azure SDK versions:

```
$ pip freeze | grep azure
azure-core==1.9.0
azure-cosmos==4.2.0
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-storage-blob==12.6.0
azure-storage-nspkg==3.1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

- Here is an [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/test/test_query.py#L533) on how to use it.
- Here is the [README file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos) for the SDK, with lots of tips and valuable information like limitations.

Comment: this example does not show how to use tokens in separate queries. This works only in the same flow, not when the token is returned to the user and the user could use it to get the next page. Like in an API request, with the token for the last processed query?

Comment: Hello! I didn't understand your question since the example has exactly a code where the user uses a token to get the next page. It only works with the last query. Tks